# How do I properly set MONGO_URL and MONGO_OPLOG_URL on a meteor galaxy deployment?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to deploy to meteor galaxy, but getting an error that the "MONGO_URL must be set in environment".  I'm using the starter template from here: https://github.com/yogiben/meteor-starter
and the example settings.json file from here:

https://galaxy.meteor.com/help/setting-environment-variables

which looks like this:

```
{ "galaxy.meteor.com": { "env": { "ROOT_URL": "https://www.example.com", "MONGO_URL": "...", "MONGO_OPLOG_URL": "..." } }, ... }
```

but I don't know what to set MONGO_URL and MONGO_OPLOG_URL to.  Anyone know what I should set them to for this particular starter template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Galaxy does not have it's own database hosting, so you'll have to go through [compose](https://compose.io/) or [MongoLab](https://mongolab.com/).  I believe MongoLab has a free tier, so once you set up a database there, you can get the URL they'll give you and set your MONGO_URL.  MongoLab's free tier doesn't have access to the Oplog, so you'd just omit that for now.